# Passing parameters to Facebook Open Graph API

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to upload a video to the Facebook open graph using the C# SDK. The video seems to upload fine and I get an Id for the activity, but only the sample metadata appears.

After a little digging, I found this:

> Before being able to publish an Open Graph action for a user and having define its corresponding connected object type in Step 3, you will now need to create a publicly accessible web page that represents this object using Open Graph metatags. Once this object page is created, you can use the Graph API to publish an action.

Since this is a client-side app, I don't have a web page that I can refer Facebook to. So how do I pass in the right parameters?

Here's my code:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters["source"] = new FacebookMediaObject { ContentType = "video/mpeg", FileName = "video.mpeg" }.SetValue(File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\sample video.MP4"));
parameters["og:title"] = "Sample video";
parameters["title"] = "Sample video";
parameters["og:description"] = "Test description";
parameters["highlight"] = "http://samples.ogp.me/287287444686523"; // If I don't put this, the upload fails
fb.PostAsync("/me/myobjectname:share", parameters);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For version 6, you can do:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
string attachementPath = @"C:\image.jpg";

using (var stream = File.OpenRead(attachementPath))
{
    dynamic result = fb.Post("me/photos",
                                new
                                    {
                                        message = "upload using Facebook C# SDK",
                                        file = new FacebookMediaStream
                                                {
                                                    ContentType = "image/jpg",
                                                    FileName = Path.GetFileName(attachementPath)
                                                }.SetValue(stream)
                                    });
}
```

More details [here](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Glimpse-into-the-Future.aspx).

Comment: I'm using version 6 of the SDK. Your code doesn't leverage the custom objects in the Open Graph API though. That's what I'm trying to figure out.